# How to create Parent Child mapping?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

Im migrating from Tire to Flex
Basic search and index-sync works
I figured the flex.parent line in the model would auto-create the _parent mapping, but it crashes
I was not able to find any parent/child demo project.

Flex.yml:

```
settings:
  number_of_shards: 5
  number_of_replicas: 1
  # analysis:
    # analyzer:
    # tokenizer:
  mappings:
    userprofile:
      startdatef:
        type: 'date'
        format: 'dateOptionalTime'
        fields:
          index: 'not_analyzed'
          untouched:
            type: 'date'
            index: 'not_analyzed'
    orgunit:
      org_name:
        type: 'string'
        index: 'analyzed'
        search_analyzer: orgunit_name_search
        index_analyzer: orgunit_name_index
      untouched:
        type: 'string'
        index: 'not_analyzed'
```

Parent model:

```
class Userprofile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Flex::ModelIndexer
  include Flex::Model
  flex.sync self
  has_many :assignments,
    -> { order(startdate: :desc) }, dependent: :restrict_with_exception

  module Search
    include Flex::Scopes
    flex.context = Userprofile
    scope :alla, query([])
  end

  # rubocop:disable all
  def flex_source
    {
      id: id,
      fullname: fullname,
      firstname: firstname,
      lastname: lastname,
      pnr: pnr,
      gender: gender,
      asscount: asscount,
      created_at: created_at,
      updated_at: updated_at,
      user_id: user_id,
      creator_id: creator_id,
    }
  end
  # rubocop:enable all
end
```

Child model:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Flex::ModelIndexer
  include Flex::Model
  flex.parent :userprofile, 'userprofile' => 'assignment' # This makes indexing break
  flex.sync self, :userprofile
  belongs_to :userprofile, counter_cache: true, touch: true

  module Search
    include Flex::Scopes
    flex.context = Assignment
    scope :alla, query([])
  end

  def flex_source
    {
      # _parent_id: userprofile_id,
      userprofile_id: userprofile_id,
      created_at: created_at,
      updated_at: updated_at
    }
  end
end
```

rake flex:import

---

Model Userprofile: Processing 37 documents in batches of 1000:
processing...: 100% ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| Time:   0:00:01
Processed 37. Successful 37. Skipped 0. Failed 0.

---

Model Assignment: Processing 36 documents in batches of 1000:
rake aborted!:   0% |                                                                                                 | ETA:  --:--:--
activerecord-4.0.2/lib/active_record/relation/batches.rb:75:in `find_in_batches'
400: {"error":"ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[Can't specify parent if no parent field has been configured]","status":400}
flex-1.0.6/lib/flex/template.rb:54:in`do_render'
...
Tasks: TOP => flex:import

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your mapping you have to specify the "parent" field. Only then ES can link the ID in the "_parent" field you want to index to the corresponding index-type. Try this as a template (substitute the variables apropriate to your index). It just adds the infos to the mapping, not removing existing ones:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/$yourIndex/$yourChildTypeName/_mapping' -d '
{
      "$yourChildTypeName" : {
         "_parent" : {
            "type" : "$yourParentTypeName"
         }
} '
```

Then try indexing again.

Comment: I wasnt able to use the exact code, and it told me i wasnt able to update the parent mapping.
But i understood what was needed and it seems i got it working with ruby

flex.yml:
    mappings:
      assignment:
        _parent:
          type: 'userprofile'

Assignment.rb:
     flex.parent :userprofile, 'userprofile' => 'assignment'
     flex.sync self, :userprofile

flex_search.yml:
barn:
    - query:
        has_child:
          type: assignment
          query:
            term:
              pg_id: <<pg_id>>

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped you. You may want to accept the answer, then.

Comment: oh im a bit new, found it :)